# What were the original Latin verbs for the Spanish verbs?

Tags: verbs, spanish, romance-languages

Spanish has evolved from Latin. The Spanish -ar, -er, and -ir verbs are also from Latin.

Accordding to http://spanishlinguist.us/2013/10/the-origins-of-spanish-ar-er-and-ir-verbs:

> Latin’s -āre verb class, which evolved into the -ar class of Spanish, was used:
>
> 1. to turn nouns and adjectives into verbs. Some examples are curare “to care” from cura “care”, navigare “sail” from navex “sailor”, and novare “to renew” from novus “new”.
> 2. for repeated or frequent actions. Some examples are dictare “recite” from dicere “say” and factitare “to practice” from facere “to do, make”.
>    for intensives (with a prefix). One example is ocupare  “to seize” from capere “to take”.
> 3. for intensives (with a prefix). One example is ocupare  “to seize” from capere “to take”.
>
> Latin’s -ēre class, which evolved into the -er class of Spanish, was used:
>
> 1. for causatives, such as monere “warn” from men “think” (i.e. to cause someone to think) and docere “to teach” from dek “accept” (i.e. to cause someone to accept).
> 2. for verbs that describe states, e.g. calere “to be hot”, frigere “to be cold”, pendere “to be hanging”.
>    Latin’s -ĕre class, which merged into the -er class of Spanish, included a group of change-of-state verbs, e.g. calescere “get hot” (from calere) and tacescere “become quiet” (from tacere “to be quiet”).
>
> Latin’s -īre class, which evolved into the -ir class of Spanish, was used:
>
> 1. to turn nouns into verbs, as in finire “to finish” from finis “end” and servire “to serve, be a slave” from servus “slave”. I don’t know what, if anything, distinguished these from the verbs-from-nouns in the -are class.
> 2. for desires, e.g. esurire “to be hungry” from esse “to eat”, parturire “to be in labor” from parere “to give birth”. "

In Spanish there are some pairs of verbs with opposite meanings, where one of them is an -ar verb, while the other one is either an -er or an -ir verb?
Examples:
"entrar" (to enter) and "salir" (to leave)
"saludar" (to greet) and "despedir" (to dismiss)
"quitar" (to remove) and "poner" (to put)
"levantar" (to awaken) and "dormir" (to sleep)

So, what was the original Latin word for "levantar" and how does it turn a noun or an adjective into a verb or how is it a repeated or frequent action? And I have the same questions for every Spanish verb I have listed in my examples.

Comment: I first tried asking the question at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/list-of-verbs-in-spanish.

Comment: This is pretty pedantic, but it feels weird to say that Latin has influences on Spanish - Spanish is a modern form of Latin!

Comment: I can't find any evidence for a noun _navex_. _Navigare_ is usually explained as from _navis_ ('ship') + the productive suffix _-igo._ If _navex_ exists, I'm sure it is a back-formation from _navigo_.

Comment: Would you really say the opposite of *odiar* (Latin *odi*, defective verb, *not* -are conjugation) is *quierer* and not *amar*? [The two aren't the same,](https://www.spanish.academy/blog/te-quiero-vs-te-amo-dont-say-the-wrong-i-love-you-in-spanish/), but I'm no Spanish native.

Comment: And even if you prefer *quierer* and not *amar*, the existence of the latter pokes holes in the idea. The grouping is a matter of arbitrary selection, a kind of Texas sharpshooter fallacy.

Comment: I couldn't find _navex (sailor)_ anywhere on **Wiktionary**, but we all know _nauta_; perhaps the OP meant that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Unfortunately, your source is slightly misleading.

It's true that verbs formed from nouns and verbs denoting repeated action in Latin tend to be in the *-āre* conjugation. However, **many other miscellaneous verbs are in the *-āre* conjugation as well**, such as *amāre* "love", *adjuvāre* "help", *lavāre* "wash"…

In most cases, the conjugation of a verb is a historical accident; Latin "cleaned up" its verb system very thoroughly, sorting all verbs into one of four or five different patterns for the present tense. So in most cases, knowing the meaning of a verb won't tell you which conjugation it falls into. For example, *audīre* and *auscultāre* both mean "hear/listen", and *imperāre* and *jubēre* both mean "command", but they've ended up in different conjugations.

Now, there are certain **suffixes** that created verbs in a specific conjugation. For example, the suffix *-scere* creates a verb meaning "to become ___" (*calēre* "to be hot" > *calēscere* "to become hot"), and these verbs always end up in the *-ere* conjugation. This is where most of the meanings listed on that website come from. But there were still, for example, many *-ere* verbs which **weren't** created with the suffix *-scere*, which had all sorts of different meanings (*dicere* "say", *currere* "run", etc).

(As a side note, the site also implies certain things are Latin when they're not. For example, the roots it lists as "men" and "dek" are actually Proto-Indo-European reconstructions, **m-n-* and **d-ḱ-*, not anything that ever existed within Latin itself. Those pertain to how the *-ēre* conjugation originally developed in the first place, not how it worked in Latin times.)

Comment: Just a minor qualification on your statement "the suffix _-scere_ creates a verb meaning "to become__"( _calēre_ 'to be hot' > _calēscere_ 'to become hot')". Strictly speaking, unprefixed _-sc-_ verbs are not telic, whereby the translation of _calescere_ as 'to become hot' is not accurate enough. As pointed out by Haverling (2010: 297-298), the suffix _-sc-_ just adds dynamicity to the stative verb, as in _calescit_ 'it is getting warmer'; the _-sco_ verbs become telic when prefixed as in _concalescit_ 'it becomes warm'. So  unprefixed -sc- verbs express *a*telic/ *in*definite change of state.

Comment: See Haverling's (2010: 299) precise translations of stative verbs (_calere_ 'to be hot'), *a*telic/ *in*definite change of state verbs (_calescere_ 'to become warm*er*'), and telic/definite change of state verbs (_concalescere_ 'to become warm'). Source: Haverling, Gerd. (2010). “Actionality, Tense, and Viewpoint”. In _Perspectives on Historical Latin Syntax_ (chap. 4, vol. II), Philip Baldi & Pierluigi Cuzzolin (eds.), 277-524. Berlin: Mouton de Gruyter.